# Найти количество отрицательных чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, if, for

Есть такое задание:

> Запросить ввод k чисел. Вводить можно отрицательные, положительные
> числа, ноль. Числа могут повторяться. Найти количество отрицательных
> чисел среди вводимых. Вывести ответ с пояснением.

В программе используется оператор цикла `for`, оператор проверки условия `if`...
Вот код, до которого я дошел:

```
k = int(input('Введите любое число '))
a = 0
for k in range(k, 1):
 if k < 0:
   print(k)
```

Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Что должно быть в пояснении?

Comment: а для этой задачи не нужно знать, как посчитать количество выведенных чисел. В задаче вообще не требуется выводить эти числа, нужно посчитать их количество.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам для "найти количество отрицательных" нужен какой-то счетчик этих самых "отрицательных", `negatives` в данном случае (или `а`, как у вас), который при выполнении условия нужно увеличивать на 1, а после цикла - вывести его на печать:

```
k = int(input('Количество чисел: '))

negatives = 0
for _ in range(k):
    num = int(input(f'Введите {_+1}-е число: '))
    if num < 0:
        negatives += 1

print(f'Вы ввели {negatives} отрицательных чисел')
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Функциональным стилем в одну строку чисто по приколу:

```
print('Отрицательных чисел:', sum(map(lambda x: int(input('Введите число: ')) < 0, range(int(input('Введите количество чисел: '))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 0
for i in range(int(input('Введите любое число: '))):
    a += int(input()) < 0
print(a)
```

Comment: большое спасибо